# change from adodb to php7.2-pgsql

Tags: phppgadmin

Change phppgadmin connection from adodb to php7.2-pgsql

Tried running an SQL query on database from phppgadmin and got error "Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /usr/share/php/adodb/adodb-error.inc.php on line 114"

In my config.inc.php I don't see anything about defining a connection type

```
    // Display name for the server on the login screen
    $conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'PostgreSQL';

    // Hostname or IP address for server.  Use '' for UNIX domain socket.
    // use 'localhost' for TCP/IP connection on this computer
    $conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'phppgadmin.com';

    // Database port on server (5432 is the PostgreSQL default)
    $conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;
```

I would like to change the default connection from adodb to php7.2-pgsql

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a newer version of phppgadmin with proper support for php7. I'd suggest just grabbing the code from git master at https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin